# Use matrix and chains in beamer animation

Tags: beamer, tikz-matrix, tikz-chains

I am trying to use beamer to generate a gif like this

[image]

I am able to get it working with `\node` and `\draw` with the following code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, matrix, chains, scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{myrect/.style n args = {4}{font=\footnotesize \ttfamily, align=left, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum width=#1cm, minimum height=#2cm, fill=#3, draw=#4}}
    \tikzset{myrect/.default={3}{1}{white}{black}}
    \tikzset{mycon/.style = {rounded corners}}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [myrect] (a) {A};
            \node [myrect, right = of a, visible on=<2->] (b) {B};
            \node [myrect, right = of b, visible on=<3->] (c) {C};
            \draw [mycon, ->, visible on=<4->] (a) to (b);
            \draw [mycon, ->, visible on=<5->] (b) to (c);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It is ok for simple flowchart, but for complex ones, I'd like to utilize `\matrix` and `\chain` in the code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, matrix, chains, scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{myrect/.style n args = {4}{font=\footnotesize \ttfamily, align=left, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum width=#1cm, minimum height=#2cm, fill=#3, draw=#4}}
    \tikzset{myrect/.default={3}{1}{white}{black}}
    \tikzset{mycon/.style = {rounded corners}}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (layer1) [matrix of nodes, nodes={myrect}, column sep=1cm] {
                A &
                |[visible on=<2->]| B &
                |[visible on=<3->]| C \\
            };
            {
                [start chain,every on chain/.style={join}, every join/.style={->}]
                \chainin (layer1-1-1) [];
                \chainin (layer1-1-2) [visible on=<4->];
                \chainin (layer1-1-3) [visible on=<5->];
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, the second one simply can't compile OK.

Are `matrix`, `chains` and `beamer` not compatible with each other? Is there any ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second approach you need a `fragile` frame (or alternatively an ampersand replacement, but I think a `fragile` frame is easier).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, matrix, chains, scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{myrect/.style n args = {4}{font=\footnotesize \ttfamily, align=left, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum width=#1cm, minimum height=#2cm, fill=#3, draw=#4}}
    \tikzset{myrect/.default={3}{1}{white}{black}}
    \tikzset{mycon/.style = {rounded corners}}
    \begin{frame}[t,fragile]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (layer1) [matrix of nodes, nodes={myrect}, column sep=1cm] {
                A &
                |[visible on=<2->]| B &
                |[visible on=<3->]| C \\
            };
            {
                [start chain,every on chain/.style={join}, every join/.style={->}]
                \chainin (layer1-1-1) [];
                \only<4->{\chainin (layer1-1-2) [];}
                \only<5->{\chainin (layer1-1-3) [];}
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So quick I get the solution! I have to say, LaTeX is so mysterious, but thanks to  guiders like you, help me grasp more and more power of it.

Comment: @EricSun You're welcome! However I have to disagree, LaTeX is not  mysterious, but TikZ certainly is :)